# How to verify the contents of ROM in FPGA

Tags: fpga, vhdl, xilinx

I'm new to FPGA and VHDL. I'm using Xilinx Spartan 3A.

I have wrote a custom ROM with initalization file .hex. I would like to verify that the rom is initalized with the values in the .hex value. Is there a method to verify the contants that is loaded from the file.

here is my design file
LIBRARY ieee;

```
 USE ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
 ------------------------------------------------------------------
 ENTITY rom IS
 PORT (address: IN INTEGER RANGE 0 TO 15;
 data_out: OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 DOWNTO 0));
 END rom;
 ------------------------------------------------------------------
 ARCHITECTURE rom OF rom IS
 SIGNAL reg_address: INTEGER RANGE 0 TO 15;
 TYPE memory IS ARRAY (0 TO 15) OF STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 DOWNTO 0);
 SIGNAL myrom: memory;
 ATTRIBUTE ram_init_file: STRING;
 ATTRIBUTE ram_init_file OF myrom: SIGNAL IS "test.coe";
 BEGIN
 data_out <= myrom(address);
 END rom;
```

I have used a test bench and I tried to simulate a ROM using initialization file but I get undefined output according to that image. [image]

```
Test bench:

-- Entity

library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity tb is
end entity;


--#############################################################################
-- Architecture

library ieee;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

architecture sim of tb is

  --===========================================================================
  -- Clock and reset decl.

  -- Clock
  constant CLK_FREQ : real := 100.0E6;  -- Clock frequency in Hz
  signal clk        : std_logic;

  -- Reset
  constant RST_PER : time := 100 ns;    -- Reset period; and then waiting for rising clk edge before deassert rst
  signal rst       : std_logic;


  --===========================================================================
  -- Device Under Test (DUT) decl.

  signal dut_address  : integer range 0 to 15;
  signal dut_data_out : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);


  --===========================================================================
  -- Test control decl.

  -- None


begin


  --===========================================================================
  -- Clock and reset impl.

  -- Clock generation
  process is
  begin
    while true loop
      clk <= '1';
      wait for 0.5 sec / CLK_FREQ;
      clk <= '0';
      wait for (1.0 sec / CLK_FREQ) - (0.5 sec / CLK_FREQ);
    end loop;
  end process;

  -- Reset generation
  process is
  begin
    rst <= '1';
    wait for RST_PER;
    wait until rising_edge(clk);
    rst <= '0';
    wait;
  end process;


  --===========================================================================
  -- Device Under Test (DUT) impl.

  rom_e : entity work.rom
    port map(
      address  => dut_address,
      data_out => dut_data_out);


  --===========================================================================
  -- Test control general

  process is
  begin
    -- Wait for reset release and clock.
    wait until rst = '0';
    wait until rising_edge(clk);
    -- Address apply and data output check
    for address in 0 to 15 loop
      wait until rising_edge(clk);
      dut_address <= address;
      wait until rising_edge(clk);
      -- Check output of ROM
    end loop;
    -- Run for a while
    wait for 1 us;
    -- End of simulation
    report "OK   ########## Sim end: OK :-) ##########   (not actual failure)" severity failure;
    wait;
  end process;

end architecture;
```

Comment: If you look in your waveform display the line labeled `/tb/rom_e/myrom` the first two locations in memory myrom are all 'U's which is a strong indication you haven't initialized it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Design functionality should be verified using simulation, for example Xilinx Isim or Mentor ModelSim.

So make a test bench and instantiate the `rom` entity, and make a number of accesses to the module.  The test bench can for example read the `test.coe` file with the expected values, and then test all addresses to be sure that the `rom` returns the expected values.

Best bech template for kick start:

```
--#############################################################################
-- Entity

library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity tb is
end entity;


--#############################################################################
-- Architecture

library ieee;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

architecture sim of tb is

  --===========================================================================
  -- Clock and reset decl.

  -- Clock
  constant CLK_FREQ : real := 100.0E6;  -- Clock frequency in Hz
  signal clk        : std_logic;

  -- Reset
  constant RST_PER : time := 100 ns;    -- Reset period; and then waiting for rising clk edge before deassert rst
  signal rst       : std_logic;


  --===========================================================================
  -- Device Under Test (DUT) decl.

  signal dut_address  : integer range 0 to 15;
  signal dut_data_out : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);


  --===========================================================================
  -- Test control decl.

  -- None


begin


  --===========================================================================
  -- Clock and reset impl.

  -- Clock generation
  process is
  begin
    while true loop
      clk <= '1';
      wait for 0.5 sec / CLK_FREQ;
      clk <= '0';
      wait for (1.0 sec / CLK_FREQ) - (0.5 sec / CLK_FREQ);
    end loop;
  end process;

  -- Reset generation
  process is
  begin
    rst <= '1';
    wait for RST_PER;
    wait until rising_edge(clk);
    rst <= '0';
    wait;
  end process;


  --===========================================================================
  -- Device Under Test (DUT) impl.

  rom_e : entity work.rom
    port map(
      address  => dut_address,
      data_out => dut_data_out);


  --===========================================================================
  -- Test control general

  process is
  begin
    -- Wait for reset release and clock.
    wait until rst = '0';
    wait until rising_edge(clk);
    -- Address apply and data output check
    for address in 0 to 15 loop
      wait until rising_edge(clk);
      dut_address <= address;
      wait until rising_edge(clk);
      -- Check output of ROM
    end loop;
    -- Run for a while
    wait for 1 us;
    -- End of simulation
    report "OK   ########## Sim end: OK :-) ##########   (not actual failure)" severity failure;
    wait;
  end process;

end architecture;


--#############################################################################
-- EOF
```

Comment: can I use Modelsim without test-bench ?

Comment: @AhmedSaleh no. You can also ride a bike without using your legs, but it makes a lot more sense to use your legs. (Or to build a quick testbench than to try and somehow magically make Modelsim guess what you need it to test)

Comment: @MarcusMüller can you show me a sample of test bench for that rom. I'm very beginner.

Comment: @AhmedSaleh: Please find answer updated with template for kick start; it is not complete, but may be a good start.

Comment: How would I load the .coe file in the test bench then verify its contents ? should I use textout ?

Comment: I must admit that I have not tried that recently, so use of the .coe file is left as an exercise for the reader ;-)  But maybe you can find some information in the Xilinx documentation of the ROM simulation model.

Comment: @MortenZilmer I have added the test bench but I'm getting undefined values

Comment: It may indicate that the ROM is not initialized correctly with the .coe file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48787/discussion-between-ahmed-saleh-and-morten-zilmer).

Comment: Hi Morten. How would I write a testbench for that? http://paste.ubuntu.com/23521751/

Comment: Still same test bench, but if the ROM does not return values, but only X's, its probably the simulation that is not initialized correctly.

Comment: How about the counters hcounter, vcounter, how would I write test bench them ?

Comment: Only place `hcounter` and `vcounter`are mentioned is in the comment above, so I have no idea what these are.

Comment: These are ports that are connected to the TOP level design. How would I work and simulate it ?

Comment: You must create a test bench for each module you want to test, thus both one for the ROM and one for the top-level design, and then you can simply apply different signals in the different test benches.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49032/discussion-between-ahmed-saleh-and-morten-zilmer).

Comment: Thanks Mortin. How would I communicate between two test benches together ? I'm using ModelSim for that